Particle Instance Modifier weird delay and origin point
Video of my scene
In my scene I have a circle with a particle system that renders no particles, then I have a sphere with the particle instance modifier attached to the circle, I want my particles to seem like they are emitted from the circle, however the origin point on the sphere particles is super strange, and my main problem is that the particles don't keep up with the emitter, they have a strange delay, parenting does not work either because it results in the particles overtaking the emitter, I have also tried every every origin point option to fix the origin point and nothing works.
Thanks for any help!

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

I the solution to this question will also fix your problem.

The answer was that I needed to apply scale.
